# Duplicate AngularJs Blocks on same page

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using Umbraco 7.3.3 together with ArcheType and I have created my own Twitter Rotator Block using AngularJS. If I add one block to the page it works well but if I add another (a Duplicate block but using different paremeters) it doesnt work.
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
var fieldset = (ArchetypeFieldsetModel)ViewData["fieldset"];
// Dynamic Block Properties entered from CMS
var propWidth = @fieldset.GetValue("blockWidth"); //blockWidth
var propScreenName = @fieldset.GetValue("blockScreenName") != null ? @fieldset.GetValue("blockScreenName") : ""; //blockScreenName
var propHashTag = @fieldset.GetValue("blockHashTag") != null ? @fieldset.GetValue("blockHashTag") : ""; //blockHashTag
var uniqueId = @fieldset.Id;
```

```
    twitterBlockModule.value("ScreenName", "@propScreenName").value("id", "@uniqueId").value("HashTag", "@propHashTag");
```

```
<div class="@Helpers.GetBootStrapWidth(propWidth)">
<div class="twitter-box">
    <h3>Twitter</h3>

    <div id="ng-apptwitter" ng-app="twitterControl" ng-controller="PostsTwitterCtrlAjax">
        <div class=" twttopquote"><br /></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="twtspinner" ng-show="loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i><br /><span class="twtSpinnerText">Loading Twitter comments...</span></div>
            <ul class="twitterlist" id="Twitterlist-@uniqueId"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="twtBottomQuote"><br /></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
var twitterBlockModule = angular.module("twitterControl", []);
 twitterBlockModule.controller("PostsTwitterCtrlAjax",
  function ($scope, $http, ScreenName, id, HashTag) {
    $scope.ScreenName = ScreenName;
    $scope.HashTag = HashTag;
    $scope.id = id;
    .....//More Code
  });
 );
```

How can I get more than one Block to work using the same JS code but passing in different parameters from seperate Blocks without it conflicting?
Thanks

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you be about more specific about how it's broken? Also, in your view, do both blocks have the same ID when you have two? (the ng-apptwitter id part). If so, that's not valid HTML, the ID must be unique.

Comment: What is the block that you're duplicating? There can only be one ng-app on a page. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp